# Windows, heroku config | grep MONGOLAB_URI

Tags: heroku, grep

I'm developing a MEAN stack app in windows and the example code I've been given to connect my mongoDB to heroku says on linux and mac the config | grep command in the title would display the full URI. On windows I get the error grep not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. I know nothing about the grep command. What would be an alternate method to do this on windows?

Answer (score 7):

grep is just a way to filter the output to make it easy to see the information you're looking for.  The Windows equivalent would be 'findstr' (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490907.aspx).  But I would just try leaving it out altogether and using your eyes to find where "MONGOLAB_URI" appears.  Assuming you don't have a ton of config, it should be easy to spot:

```
> heroku config
```

Comment: Thank you! It was very easy to spot I figured there was an easy work around that I didn't understand. I've never used heroku before until now and the command find it I looked up was the one with grep, I didn't realize just running heroku config would show it itself. Thanks again.